# Square root of Big-Theta?

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, proof-explanation

Is there a method for simplifying a Big Theta equation that is under a square root? For example:
$$ 
\Theta(\sqrt{\Theta(n^2)})
$$

I know there is the property that states that

$$ 
\Theta(\Theta(n)) = \Theta(n)
$$

but is it possible to go from the first equation to a simplified version - hopefully without the square root? Is it correct to assume that this property does not apply to Big-Oh, Big-Omega, and Big-Theta when it is raised to a power? Such as this:
$$
\Theta(\Theta(n)^{1/2})\neq \Theta(n)
$$
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One can try using the definitions directly.

Let $f(n) = \Theta(n^2)$, so there exist constants $k_1, k_2$ and $n_1$ such that for $n> n_1$, we have
$k_1 n^2 \leq f(n) \leq k_2 n^2$. Clearly this will also imply that for $n> n_1$, we have $\sqrt{k_1} n \leq \sqrt{f(n)} \leq \sqrt{k_2} n$ (why we did this will be clear in a moment).

Similarly, let $g(n) = \Theta(\sqrt{f(n)})$, so there exist constants $k_3, k_4$ and $n_2$ such that for $n> n_2$, we have
$k_3 \sqrt{f(n)} \leq g(n) \leq k_4 \sqrt{f(n)}$. Now we can use the bounds derived earlier, provided we ensure $n > n_1$. How do we do that? Naturally, let $n_3 = \max(n_1, n_2)$ and consider only $n > n_3$, so both sets of inequalities are applicable.

\begin{align*}
k_3\sqrt{k_1}\sqrt{n} \leq k_3\sqrt{f(n)} &\leq g(n) \leq k_4\sqrt{f(n)}\leq k_4\sqrt{k_2} n \\
k_5 n &\leq g(n) \leq k_6 n
\end{align*}

where $k_5 = k_3\sqrt{k_1}$ and $k_6 = k_4\sqrt{k_2}$.
By definition, $g(n) = \Theta(n)$ as we just found the appropriate constants.

> Is it correct to assume that this property does not apply to Big-Oh, Big-Omega, and Big-Theta when it is raised to a power?

Now you can try answering those three distinct questions yourself by applying the definitions and trying to proceed in a similar manner as above. **Hint** (for $\Theta$ version): consider the function $h(n) = n$. Clearly $h(n) = \Theta(n)$. Is the statement $\Theta(\sqrt{h(n)}) = \Theta(n)$ true?